# How do I construct a std::string from a DWORD?

Tags: c++, numeric, stdstring

I have following code:

```
Tools::Logger.Log(string(GetLastError()), Error);
```

`GetLastError()` returns a `DWORD` a numeric value, but the constructor of `std::string` doesn't accept a `DWORD`.

What can I do?

Comment: (Moved from non-answer) Read [The String Formatters of Manor Farm](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm) by Herb Sutter.  It's a great comparison of the different ways to convert data to strings, including std::stringstream, Boost::lexical_cast, sprintf, snprintf, and std::strstream.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You want to read up on ostringstream:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   std::ostringstream stream;
   int i = 5;
   stream << i;
   std::string str = stream.str();
}
```

Comment: that's funny... who would downvote this? I wouldn't think this would be controversial :)

Comment: If you forget #include <sstream> you will get a strange error message: "error: aggregate ‘std::ostringstream ...’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined". Simple fix.

Comment: Most answers have got exactly one downvote. Could it be somebody downvoted every answer but their own? Unfortunately there is more than one suspect :)

Comment: @David They'd have to be one of the high-rep folks. I wonder where all that Jon Skeet rep goes...

Answer (score 22):

You want to convert the number to a `string`:

```
std::ostringstream os;
os << GetLastError();
Log(os.str(), Error);
```

Or `boost::lexical_cast`:

```
Log(boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(GetLastError()), Error);
```

Answer (score 21):

**Since C++11**

[`std::to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) with overloads for `int`, `long`, `long long`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, `unsigned long long`, `float`, `double`, and `long double`.

```cpp
#include <string>

auto i = 1337;
auto si = std::to_string(i); // "1337"
auto f = .1234f;
auto sf = std::to_string(f); // "0.123400"
```

*Yes, I'm a fan of [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto).*

To use your example:

```cpp
Tools::Logger.Log(std::to_string(GetLastError()), Error);
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks for teaching me about C++'s auto. I'm assuming it's the c++ equivalent of 'var' that c# has?

Comment: Yes, see [the page I referenced](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto). I'm no C# expert so there could be minor differences though.

Comment: why i got namespace 'std' has no member "to_string()" ?

Comment: @gumuruh You most likely did not `#include <string>`.

Answer (score 9):

Use Boost's [`lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) for simple cases such as the above:

```
Tools::Logger.Log(lexical_cast<string>(GetLastError()), Error);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [STLSoft](http://www.stlsoft.org/)'s [winstl::int_to_string()](http://www.stlsoft.org/doc-1.9/int__to__string_8hpp.html), as follows:

```
Tools::Logger.Log(winstl::int_to_string(GetLastError()), Error);
```

Also, if you want to lookup the string form of the error code, you can use STLSoft's [winstl::error_desc](http://www.stlsoft.org/doc-1.9/classwinstl_1_1basic__error__desc.html).

There were a bunch of articles in [Dr Dobb's](http://www.ddj.com/) about this a few years ago: parts [one](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184401596), [two](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403874), [three](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403880), [four](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403882). Goes into the subject in *great* detail, particularly about performance.

Answer (score 1):

Use std::stringstream.

```
std::stringstream errorStream;
errorStream << GetLastError();
Tools::Logger.Log(errorStream.str(), Error);
```

Answer (score 0):

what i normally do is:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << GetLastError() << " :: " << Error << std::endl;
Tools::Logger.Log(oss.str()); // or whatever interface is for logging
```

Answer (score 0):

As all guys here suggested, implementation will use stringstream. 
In my current project we created function

```
template <typename T>
std::string util::str::build( const T& value );
```

to create string from any source.

So in our project it would be

```
Tools::Logger.Log( util::str::build(GetLastError()) );
```

Such usage of streams in the suggested way wouldn't pass my review unless someone wrap it.

Comment: Do you like how it looks? Can you specify it for work with doubles. For work with your own type which can't be used with the stream?