# convert int to std::string

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [int to std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893670/int-to-stdstring)

How can you convert int to std::string?

Comment: See [int to std::string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893670/int-to-stdstring)

Answer (score 15):

you can use stringstream; stole this from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/1057/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
  int number = 123;

  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << number;

  std::cout << ss.str() << endl;
}
```