# How to find an integer inside a string representing a binary file

Tags: c++

How can I find an integer inside a string representing a binary file?

For example,

```
const std::string pe_file_path(argv[1]);
std::ifstream pe_file(pe_file_path, std::ios_base::binary);
const std::string pe_file_content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(pe_file)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
DWORD some_value = 0x243e0c10;
// pe_file_content.find(???);
```

I need to know `some_value`'s position inside the string.

How can I do it?

Now I'm using the following solution

```
std::ostringstream some_value_sstr;
some_value_sstr << std::hex << some_value;

std::ostringstream tmp;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
  tmp << (char)std::stoi(some_value_sstr.str().substr(i * 2, 2), 0, 16);
}
std::cout << std::hex << pe_file_content.find(tmp.str()) << std::endl;
```

but I guess there can be more elegant solution to this problem.

Comment: You mean like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e750f84f0ccfb0f)? Be careful with endianess. I don't know if `std::string` is the best choice for binary data either...

Comment: @Simon Kraemer Well, yeah. But I already have a `DWORD` variable

Comment: Is it always a `DWORD` you are searching for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `pe_file_content` contains the four bytes `0x24`, `0x3E`, `0x0C`, and `0x10`, and not the eight bytes representing them as characters, then you need to convert your `DWORD` value to a string containing those same bytes, and then you can just search for that:

```
std::string needle(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&some_value), sizeof(some_value));
pe_file_content.find(needle);
```

Be careful with byte order.  If the integer in your file doesn't have the same endieness as your machine, you'll need to reverse the byte order of `some_value` before searching.

Comment: Is it safe to use `reinterpret_cast` like this?

Comment: This is exactly the case that `reinterpret_cast` exists for.  The strict aliasing rules explicitly make an exception for referring to any object via a `char*`.

Comment: In case you only use `DWORD` (4 byte values) you can also do the conversion manually:
`std::string some_value_str = {{
  (char)((some_value & 0xFF000000) >> 24), 
  (char)((some_value & 0x00FF0000) >> 16), 
  (char)((some_value & 0x0000FF00) >> 8), 
  (char)((some_value & 0x000000FF) >> 0) 
 }};`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use the same approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893670/how-do-i-construct-a-stdstring-from-a-dword) to convert the DWORD to a stringstream and the use the string::find function to find the position of the number.

Comment: You mean like this? `std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << some_value;
    pe_file_content.find(oss.str());` It won't work as expected