# Convert DWORD to String with c++

Tags: c++

I get Idmachine with GetVolumeInformation command. I want changed idmachine (DWORD) to string then show in TEdit(C++ builder) but not. Please help me!

```
GetVolumeInformation(L"C:\\",NULL,NULL,&dwVolSerial,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
std::wstring wstr = std::to_wstring(idmachine);
std::string str = std::string(wstr.begin(), wstr.end());
ShowMessage(str);
```

Error 
Vcl.Dialogs.hpp(1430): candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string, allocator >') to 'const System::UnicodeString' for 1st argument

Comment: GetVolumeInformation(L"C:\\",NULL,NULL,&dwVolSerial,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    std::wstring wstr = std::to_wstring(dwVolSerial);
    std::string str = std::string(wstr.begin(), wstr.end());
    ShowMessage(str);

Comment: Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893670/how-do-i-construct-a-stdstring-from-a-dword) helps